# Android SharedPreference not clear after reinstall

Tags: android, installation

I have developed an application that stores a boolean to a `SharePreference` to identify whether application start at the first time after installation. The problem is when I uninstall and install it again it still remember all `SharedPreference` that I have set on previous installation, I can't check whether application start at the first time after installation.
This happen on **Samsung galaxy s version 2.2.1**.

I appreciate your suggestion on the way to check first start.

I found it strange too, but I have tested it with other devices, same version and difference version, and not found this issue. I only found this issue only on one single device.

Here is my code, please tell me if you found something wrong :

```
   public static boolean isFirstStart(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstTime = pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, true);
    if (isFirstTime) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, false);
        editor.putBoolean("test", false);
        editor.commit();
    }

    return isFirstTime;
}
```

This method return true only the first installation, but false for later installation.
Note: I always uninstall and install to test it. I have try to clear this application data in setting the problem is still the same, but it is ok if do this  pref.edit().clear().commit(); it will be cleared for this installation.

Comment: Have you tried it on other devices?

Comment: Please show the code that reads the preference and verifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have come across the same problem. If your application is already installed in the device and if you are trying to install your new app on top of your old app this problem arises. Android just overwrites things thus leaving your preference just the way they were. So what you have to do is, you have to uninstall your app and only after which you can reinstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Samsung galaxy s version 2.2.1 and had used SharedPreference and I did not get any such problem. Make sure you are not using global SharedPreference name and recheck your code. I am sure you will find it and if still you find the problem then plz show your code.

Comment: Here is my code: public static boolean isFirstStart(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstTime = pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, true);
    if (isFirstTime) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, false);
        editor.putBoolean("test", false);
        editor.commit();
    }

    return isFirstTime;
}

Comment: your code looks fine. Change the preference name may be it is conflicting with other app's pref name I guess.

Comment: Ok i will try. I have test google iosched 2011, it have the same problem on this device. It is not show the EULA for second install.

Comment: Thank vineetska, i solved it by change add my package name to preference name. millions thanks